# QNetworkAccessManager send data incomplete

Tags: qt, qnetworkaccessmanager

I have a trouble with QNetworkAccessManager in windows. I wrote the following code to submit request ,it works on ubuntu perfectly but on windows send just 16384 bytes!! It seems request execute just once and freeze.

```
QString concatenated = username + ":" + pass;
QByteArray hash = concatenated.toLocal8Bit().toBase64();
QString headerData = "Basic " + hash;
QNetworkRequest request = QNetworkRequest(QUrl(baseURL));

request.setRawHeader("Authorization", headerData.toLocal8Bit());
request.setRawHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

QNetworkReply * reply = nam->post(request,data);
connect(reply,&QNetworkReply::uploadProgress,this,&myClass::uploadProgress);
```

in `uploadProgress` method:

```
qDebug() << sent << " " << total;
if(total && sent){
    int result = (sent*100)/total;
    emit uploaded(result);
}
```

output:

```
16384 632054 // AND EVERY THINGS STOP UNTIL I GET QNetworkReply::RemoteHostClosedError ERROR CODE
```

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing a complete [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), rather than just snippets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After two days finally, I found why it happened! It because I emit the signal in uploadProgress directly! I changed the `uploadProgress` code like below and it works perfectly now!

```
qDebug() << sent << " " << total;
if(total && sent){
    int result = (sent*100)/total;
    QTimer::singleShot(5,[this,result](){
       emit uploaded(result);   
    }
}
```